# Trouble using a script

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I got a problem which i might have some problem explaining without sharing hte files. But I will try. The site is only local at the moment.

I am working on a wordpress theme which uses custom posts and taxonomies. Every custom posts (3 in total) have their own single view.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div id="singleprodukt">
        <div class="produktbilde">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(220,220)); ?>

        </div>
        <div class="produktinnhold">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <div class="entry-content">

            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Endre'), '<p>', '</p>' ); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>

    <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'farge', 'Farge: ', ', ', '' ); ?>
    <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'glasstype', 'Glasstype: ', ', ', '' ); ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php include('fore.php');?>
```

And I got someone to make a form for me, that would use the custom taxonomies, and have a sort of "order" system to it, to just send mail. Either "Send now" or "Send more"

```
<?
//Sjekke om noe har blitt aktiver/satt


//Om det er valgt � sende fler foresp�rsler "husker" vi produkt-id midlertidig
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {


//Litt validering av inputs her og.
//Dropper validering av epost nå da denne blir validert senere. 


 if($_POST['bredde']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt bredde p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['hoyde']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt hoyde p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['farge']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt type farge p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['glass']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt glasstype p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['hengsel']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt hengselside p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['aapning']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt &aring;pningsrettning p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}


if($stop == 1){

    echo '<div id="overlay"><div id="box"><h1>Beklager, men noen feil ble opptaget. Vennligst rett opp dette.</h1>';
    echo $error ;
    echo '<p><br /><br /><br /><A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="feilknapp" title="Klikk her for &aring; g&aring; tilbake &aring; pr&oslash;ve igjen.">G&aring; tilbake</A><br /></p>';
    echo "</div><>/div>"; 



}

if(!$stop ==1){ 
//Starte session
session_start();


/*Hente informasjon fra DB og gjøre om til variabler..*/

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//ID:
the_ID() == $id;

$resultat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='.$id.'");
while($row == mysql_fetch_array($resultat))
{
$produktid = $row['ID'];
$produktnavn = $row['post_content'];
$dato = date('F');

}

//Litt variabelmagi 


 $nofilename = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
 $nofilename = str_replace(".", "", $nofilename);
 $prodnummer = $row['ID'];
 $bredde  = $_POST['bredde'];
 $hoyde  = $_POST['hoyde'];
 $farge  = $_POST['farge'];
 $glasstype  = $_POST['glass'];
 $hengsel  = $_POST['hengsel'];
 $aapning  = $_POST['aapning'];
 $kommentar  = $_POST['kommentar'];
 $navn   = $_POST['navn'];
 $telefon  = $_POST['telefon'];
 $epost   = $_POST['email'];
//øverste del av handlevogn
    echo '<div id="overlay"><div id="box"><h1>Foresp&oslash;rsel midlertidig lagret.</h1>';
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<table border="1" callpadding="0" width="98%" class="table">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="background-color:#F2F2F2">Produktnr.</td><td style="background-color:white">Bredde & H&oslash;yde</td><td style="background-color:#F2F2F2">Farge</td><td>Glasstype</td><td style="background-color:#F2F2F2">Hengselside</td><td>&Aring;pning</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<table border="1" callpadding="0" width="98%" class="table">';    

//lagre i en midlertidig txtfil som slettes når forespørselen er sendt.

$_POST['kommentar'] = str_replace ("\n", "<br />", $_POST['kommentar']);

//Lagre så i en midlertidig fil
if (!file_exists($nofilename)) {
    fopen($nofilename.".txt", "W+");
}

  $fp = fopen($nofilename.".txt", "a");

   $fs = "Produkt ID : " . "|" . $row['ID'] . ". - Bredde : " . "|" . $_POST['bredde'] . ". - H&oslash;yde : " . "|" . $_POST['hoyde'] . ". - Farge : " . "|" . $_POST['farge'] . ". - Glasstype : " . "|" . $_POST['glass'] . ". - Hengselside : " . "|" . $_POST['hengsel']. ". - &Aring;pningsretning : " . "|" . $_POST['aapning'] . ". - Tilleggsinformasjon : " . "|" . $_POST['kommentar'] . "<br />" . "\n";

  fwrite($fp, $fs);





/*vise "handevogn" med antall forespørsler*/
//åpne og vise resultat
 $foresporsler = file($nofilename.".txt");
 $foresporsler = array_reverse($foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('Produkt ID :', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - Bredde : ', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - H&oslash;yde : ', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - Farge : ', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - Glasstype : ', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - Hengselside : ', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - &Aring;pningsretning : ', '', $foresporsler);
 $foresporsler = str_replace('. - Tilleggsinformasjon : ', '', $foresporsler);
 foreach ($foresporsler AS $tmp){


   $array = explode("|", $tmp);




//Visning av ny rad
    echo '<tr><td style="background-color:#F2F2F2" title="Produktnummer">'.$array[1].'</td><td style="background-color:white" title="Bredde & h&oslash;yde">'.$array[2].' * '.$array[3].'</td><td style="background-color:#F2F2F2" title="Farge">'.$array[4].'</td><td title="Glasstype">'.$array[5].'</td><td style="background-color:#F2F2F2" title="Hengselside">'.$array[6].'</td><td title="&Aring;pning">'.$array[7].'</t></tr>';
  }
//slutten av tabellen    
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<p><br /><br /><br /><A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="feilknapp" title="Klikk her for &aring; legge til flere foresp&oslash;rsler i listen">Legg til fler produktforesp&oslash;rsler i listen.</A><br><br><hr><br>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="submit" name="sendsporsel" value="Send forsp&oslash;rsel n&aring;" class="feilknapp"><br /></p>';
    echo '<p>Ditt navn :<br /><input type="text" value="'.$_POST['navn'].'" name="navn"></p>';
 echo '<p>Ditt tlfnummer :<br /><input type="text" value="'.$_POST['telefon'].'" name="telefon"></p>';
    echo '<p>Din epostadresse :<br /><input type="text" value="'.$_POST['email'].'" name="email"></p>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value ="'.$nofilename.'" name="innehold">';
    echo "</div></div>"; 



/*Stopp på vise handlevogn-kode*/
  }



} 

//Dersom send forespørsler nå er klikket
  if (isset($_POST['sendsporsel'])) {

//Sjekke om navn, tlf og epost er utfyld

//epostvalidering
$epost_sjekk = !preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST['email']);
//selve validering 
 if($_POST['navn']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Ditt navn.</p>";}
 if($_POST['telefon']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Ditt telefonnummer.</p>";}
 if($_POST['email']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Din epostadresse.</p>";}
 if($epost_sjekk == 1 AND $_POST['email'] != 1 AND !$_POST['email']=='') { $stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Epostadressen er ikke godkjent.<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='email' title='Din korrekte epostadresse'></p>";}

if($stop == 1){

    echo '<div id="overlay"><div id="box"><h1>Beklager, men f&oslash;r vi kan behandle din hendvendelse m&aring; vi ha yttligere informasjon.</h1>';
    echo $error ;
    echo '<br /><hr>';
    echo '<p><br /><br /><br /><A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="feilknapp" title="Klikk her for &aring; g&aring; tilbake &aring; pr&oslash;ve igjen.">G&aring; tilbake</A><br /></p>';
    echo "</div></div></form>"; 



}
//Om ingen felter mangler
if(!$stop ==1 OR $_POST['sendsporsel2']){ 
//tilbakemelding
//åpne filen

 echo '<div id="overlay"><div id="box"><h1>foresp&oslash;rseler sendt..</h1>';
 echo '<p>Takk, din foresp&oslash;rsel er sendt til v&aring;rt kontor som epost og vi svarer deg s&aring; snart vi har mulighet.</p>';
 echo '<p><br /><br /><br />Dette vinduet stenges automatisk n&aring;r eposten er sendt. <br /><br /><br /></p>';
 echo '<meta (here is normally just http, but I coulden't post url when I tried to post this message)-equiv="Refresh" content="5; URL=fore.php" >';
    echo "</div></div>";

//utsendelse av epost



  $mottaker = 'robin@comfyrene.com';//mottager av mailen
  $emne = "Forespørsel fra Dør & Vindu";//emne p� mailen
  $inneholds = file_get_contents($_POST['innehold'].".txt");
  $inneholds = str_replace('|', '', $inneholds);
  $inneholds = str_replace('\n', '<br />', $inneholds);
  $headers = 'From: Techmind <post@techmind.no>' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: '.$_POST["email"].'' . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";



  $melding = "Hei.<br><br>
     Det har blitt lagt inn en foresp&oslash;rsel ang&aring;ende f&oslash;lgende produkteter.<br />

     ---------------------------------
     <br /><br />
     {$inneholds}
     <br />
     ---------------------------------
     <br /><br />
     Navn p&aring; kunde : {$_POST['navn']}<br />
     Telefonnummer kunde : {$_POST['telefon']}<br />
     Kundes epostadresse : {$_POST['email']}<br /><br />

     ";}

  mail($mottaker, $emne, $melding, $headers); 

//utsendelse av epost-stopp!
//Slette den midlertidige filen
$slettefil = $_POST['innehold'].".txt";
unlink($slettefil);
//slette sessions
session_unset();
session_destroy();
  }




//dersom det er valgt å sende en forespørsel viser vi resten av skjemaet
if (isset($_POST['submit1']) AND !$_POST['submit2']) {

//Sjekke om nødvendige felter er fylt i og godkjente

//epostvalidering
$epost_sjekk = !preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST['email']);

 if($_POST['bredde']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt bredde p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['hoyde']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt hoyde p&aring; produktet.."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['farge']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt type farge p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['glass']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt glasstype p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['hengsel']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt hengselside p&aring; produktet."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['aapning']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke valgt &aring;pningsrettning p&aring; produktet.."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['navn']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke skrevet inn ditt navn."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['telefon']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke skrevet inn ditt telefonnummer."."</p>";}
 if($_POST['email']=='') {$stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Du har ikke skrevet inn noen epostadresse."."</p>";}
 if($epost_sjekk == 1 AND $_POST['email'] != 1 AND !$_POST['email']=='') { $stop = 1;$error .= "<p><font color='red'>&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>Epostadressen er ikke godkjent.</p>";}

if($stop == 1){

    echo '<div id="overlay"><div id="box"><h1>Beklager, men noen feil ble opptaget. Vennligst rett opp dette.</h1>';
    echo $error ;
    echo '<p><br /><br /><br /><A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="feilknapp" title="Klikk her for &aring; g&aring; tilbake &aring; pr&oslash;ve igjen.">G&aring; tilbake</A><br /></p>';
    echo "</div></div>"; 



}

if(!$stop ==1){


/*Sending av epost*/
  $mottaker = 'robin@comfyrene.com';//mottager av mailen
  $emne = "Forespørsel fra Dør & Vindu";//emne p� mailen
  $bredde = $_POST['bredde'];
  $hoyde = $_POST['hoyde'];
  $farge = $_POST['farge'];
  $glasstype = $_POST['glass'];
  $hengsel = $_POST['hengsel'];
  $aapning = $_POST['aapning'];
  $kommentar = $_POST['kommentar'];
  $epost = $_POST['email'];
  $headers = 'From: Techmind <post@techmind.no>' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: meg@meg.no' . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";



  $melding = "Hei.<br><br>
     Det har blitt lagt inn en foresp&oslash;rsel ang&aring;ende produktet '{$produktnavn}'.<br />
     Beskjeden er som f&oslash;lger : <br />
     ---------------------------------
     <br /><br />
     Bredde :{$bredde}
     <br />
     H&oslash;yde : {$hoyde}
     <br />
     Farge : {$farge}
     <br />
     Glasstype : {$glasstype}
     <br />
     Hengselside : {$hengsel}
     <br />
     &Aring;pningsretning : {$aapning}
     <br />
     Kommentar : {$kommentar}
     <br /><br />
     -----------------------------------
     <br /><br />
     Navn p&aring; kunde : {$_POST['navn']}<br />
     Telefonnummer kunde : {$_POST['telefon']}<br />
     Kundes epostadresse : {$_POST['email']}<br /><br />
     ";

  mail($mottaker, $emne, $melding, $headers); 

/*Sende epost stopp*/

//Ge en liten beskjed om at den er sendt..
 echo '<div id="overlay"><div id="box"><h1>foresp&oslash;rsel sendt..</h1>';
 echo '<p>Takk, din foresp&oslash;rsel er sendt til v&aring;rt kontor som epost og vi svarer deg s&aring; snart vi har mulighet.</p>';
 echo '<p><br /><br /><br />Dette vinduet stenges automatisk n&aring;r eposten er sendt. <br /><br /><br /></p>';
 echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; URL=fore.php" >';
    echo "</div></div>";


}}
if (!isset($_POST['submit1']) AND !$_POST['submit2']) {


?>
<br /><br /><br />
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    <table cellspacing="0" table border="0" cellpadding="2" align="left">

<tr>
 <th>Bredde x H&oslash;yde:</th>
 <td colspan="3"><input name="bredde" type="text" size="3" maxlength="4" value="" /><b>x</b><input name="hoyde" type="text" size="3" maxlength="4" value="" /><i>(mm)</i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th align="left">Farge (RAL kode):</th>
     <td colspan="3"><select name="farge">
        <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Standard RAL 9010">RAL 9010 Hvit (standard)</option>
     <option value="Annen RAL kode">Annen RAL kode</option>
     <option value="Ubehandlet">Ubehandlet</option>
     </select>

     </td>
</tr>

<tr>
     <th align="left">Glasstype:</th>
     <td colspan="3"><select name="glass">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Tolags energiglass (standard)">Tolags energiglass (standard)</option>
     <option value="Riflet glass">Riflet glass</option>

     <option value="Matt glass">Matt glass</option>
     </select>

     </td>
</tr>

<tr>
     <th align="left">Hengselside:</th>

     <td colspan="3"><select name="hengsel">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="H&oslash;yre">H&oslash;yre</option>
     <option value="Venstre">Venstre</option>
     </select>

     </td>
</tr>

<tr>
       <th align="left">&Aring;pningsretning:</th>
       <td colspan="3"><select name="aapning">
    <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Utover">Utover</option>
     <option value="Innover">Innover</option>

     </select>

    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
 <th>Navn:</th>
 <td colspan="3"><input name="navn" type="text" size="25" maxlength="150" value="" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <th>Telefon:</th>
 <td colspan="3"><input name="telefon" type="text" size="25" maxlength="8" value="" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <th>E-post:</th>
 <td colspan="3"><input name="email" type="text" size="25" maxlength="150" value="" /></td>

</tr>


<tr>
 <th valign="top">Kommentar:</th>
 <td colspan="3"><textarea name="kommentar" cols="29" rows="4"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td colspan="0"><input name="submit1" type="submit" value="Send foresp&oslash;rsel" /></td><td colspan="0"><input name="submit2" type="submit" value="Send flere foresp&oslash;rsler" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form></p>

<?}?>
```

However. That doesn't work. It work on his system though: techmind.no/kunder/c/fore.php - I have tried to reach him several times, but he has gotten sick, so I haven't been able to talk to him for a while. It works on his system, but it doesn't work on mine (using wamp by the way)

I would love it if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong her. The files might be long here, and it seems it breaks up real strange, for that I am sorry.

Comment: And it seems this was quite breaken up when I postet it. Sorry for that. Hope it make sense anyways. First time user on this site ;)

Comment: Do you get a error message? Or what part of it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes, a box appear (all messed up) and then I rederict and see this: Fatal error: Call to undefined function taxonomy_exist() in C:\wamp\www\dorogvindu\wp-content\themes\dorogvindu\content.php on line 3

Comment: But it seems to work as intended here: http://techmind.no/kunder/c/fore.php, just  not on my (local) site which is a wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

the_ID() == $id;

I have never seen this kind of thing before. a function that is compare to something without using the if statement? or a version of inline if statement?

Comment: That statement would evaluate to either true or false and the result would be discarded, other than side effects of `the_ID()`, if any.